# Entity Framework 6 - Update DB record by copying another DB record

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I just started with Asp.NET MVC & EF and I am guessing there must be an easy solution for what I am trying to do.

What I want to do:

Update an existing db record with the values of another db record.

In my Post Controller action I pass the ID of the original record and the ID of the record the should be copied over the original one.

```
var orgRecord = ctx.Model.Where(x => x.ID == vm.ID)...
var copyRecord = ctx.Model.Where(x => x.ID == vm.IDtoCopy)...
```

I have tried different approaches but I always get an error that **ID** "is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified"

Here are some of my tries:

```
 orgRecord.ID = copyRecord.ID

 ctx.Entry(orgRecord).CurrentValues.SetValues(copyRecord);
 ctx.Entry(orgRecord).State = EntityState.Modified;
 ctx.Entry(orgRecord).Property(x => x.ID).IsModified = false;
```

What do I need to do in order to copy all properties but leaving the primary key untouched?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try following: Get the `copyRecord` with `AsNoTracking()`, then set the ID to the original value, then attach to context, set State to Modified and save.